# Подсветка выбранного блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".slot").click(function() {
  open_slot();
});

function api_call(url, data, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success || data.success == "true") {
        callback(null, data);
      } else {
        callback(data.error, null);
      }
    }
  });
}

function open_slot() {
  api_call('api url', {}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      if (result.result == 1) {
        $(".result").html("вы выбрали верно!");
        // добавляем блоку на который тыкнули класс "select", и всем остальным класс "block"
      } else {
        $(".result").html("вы выбрали не верно!");
        // Тут рандомно надо добавить в один из блоков (исключая блок на который мы нажали) class "select", а всем остальным класс "block". Чтобы якобы показать где на самом деле был правильный вариант.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.slot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.slot.select {
  background: green;
}

.slot.block {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

В коде все описал

Comment: Ну ты же всё описал. Делай ровно то, что описал словами - только кодом.

Comment: Пробовал реализовать с тегом "this", но по логике клик не передает this в функцию, если сделаю просто добавление в каждый класс - получится не то что нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучшее решение я считаю - использовать коллбек, в котором будет меняться отображение объектов.

К слову, добавил условие `$(".slot").hasClass("select") || $(".slot").hasClass("block")`, которое проверяет, выбирали ли мы уже объект и если да, то предотвращает выбор еще одного.

Вот так:

```js
$(".slot").click(function() {
  if ($(".slot").hasClass("select") ||
    $(".slot").hasClass("block")) {
    return;
  }

  let thisEl = $(this);
  open_slot(function(result) {
    if (result) {
      $(".result").html("вы выбрали верно!");
      thisEl.addClass("select");
    } else {
      $(".result").html("вы выбрали не верно!");
      $(".slot").addClass("block");
      let slots = $(".slot").not(thisEl);
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * slots.length);
      $(slots[random]).addClass("select").removeClass("block");
    }
  });
});

function open_slot(callback) {
  callback(false); // это надо удалить
  return;          // (костыль для проверки)
  api_call('api url', {}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      callback(result.result);
    }
  });
}

function api_call(url, data, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success || data.success == "true") {
        callback(null, data);
      } else {
        callback(data.error, null);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.slot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.slot.select {
  background: green;
}

.slot.block {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slot">
  <div class="slot_result">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: в функции open_slot будет api_call запрос, поэтому и нужна отдельная функция

Comment: `open_slot` сообщает, что она открывает слот, но никак не то, что там будет запрос. Обновил ответ.

Comment: изменил код в вопросе, добавил пример запроса api_call

Comment: @kiLLro очему вы не передаете данные о нажатом блоке в API? Как она узнает, верный ли слот выбран?

Comment: Пользователь никак не влияет на то что ему отдаст API. Он просто нажал на кнопку, а сервер уже решил что именно ему нужно отдать

Comment: @kiLLro здрасте-приехали... А как сервер узнает, на какую из кнопок нажал пользователь? Или он рандомно возвращает true/false?

Comment: Сервер возвращает result  = 1 или 0. (Рандомно)

Comment: @kiLLro а есть смысл? Рандомность можно и без сервера на `JS` непосредственно сделать...

Comment: Смысл есть, я показал пример как нужно, только никак не могу прийти к правильному решению

Comment: Опять же не важно на какой слот нажал юзер, везде одна и та же функция

Comment: @kiLLro как скажете. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста пример моей функции open_slot, там чуть другая структура обращения к API. Там есть 2 результата true и false

Comment: @kiLLro т.е. вы не допускаете изменения количесива входных параметров вашей функции `open_slot()`? Добавить туда параметр с `callback` нельзя?

Comment: Можно и так сказать. API лишь отдает результат, который нужно отобразить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59449/discussion-between-killro-and-ags17).

Comment: Попасть вообще возможно? я несколько минут клацал мимо :D

Comment: @Alban если вы приглядитесь, в первые две строки `open_slot()` вставлен костыль